# PostgreSQL full backups script not working

Tags: linux, bash, backup, hostname, postgresql-9.2

I'd like to use backup script that is provided in (my scripts are the same as in given link, only configuration changed):

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Automated_Backup_on_Linux

In pg_backup.config
I added:

```
BACKUP_USER = myusername (that has postgresql superuser access)
HOST = localhost
USERNAME = myusername (that has postgresql superuser access)
```

Update full pg_backup.config:

```
##############################
## POSTGRESQL BACKUP CONFIG ##
##############################

# Optional system user to run backups as.  If the user the script is running as doesn't match this
# the script terminates.  Leave blank to skip check.
BACKUP_USER=myusername

# Optional hostname to adhere to pg_hba policies.  Will default to "localhost" if none specified.
HOSTNAME=localhost

# Optional username to connect to database as.  Will default to "postgres" if none specified.
USERNAME=myusername

# This dir will be created if it doesn't exist.  This must be writable by the user the script is
# running as.
BACKUP_DIR=/home/myusername/openerp/7.0/backup

# List of strings to match against in database name, separated by space or comma, for which we only
# wish to keep a backup of the schema, not the data. Any database names which contain any of these
# values will be considered candidates. (e.g. "system_log" will match "dev_system_log_2010-01")
SCHEMA_ONLY_LIST=""

# Will produce a custom-format backup if set to "yes"
ENABLE_CUSTOM_BACKUPS=no

# Will produce a gzipped plain-format backup if set to "yes"
ENABLE_PLAIN_BACKUPS=yes


#### SETTINGS FOR ROTATED BACKUPS ####

# Which day to take the weekly backup from (1-7 = Monday-Sunday)
DAY_OF_WEEK_TO_KEEP=5

# Number of days to keep daily backups
DAYS_TO_KEEP=7

# How many weeks to keep weekly backups
WEEKS_TO_KEEP=5
```

But when I try to run pg_backup.sh with command:

```
bash pg_backup.sh
```

I get this error message:

```
Performing full backups
--------------------------------------------

psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "shows my external IP", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "shows my external ip", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off

All database backups complete!
```

Also it prints out that all databases are complete, but it does not do any backups.

When I try this command manually:

```
pg_dump -Fp -h "localhost" -U "myusername" "mydatabase" | gzip > /home/myusername/openerp/7.0/backup/"mydatabase".sql.gz;
```

Then it does backup perfectly!

So the question is why does it give such wierd error?
First it uses my external ip, when it should use localhost, second it connects with postgres user (or at least it shows like that), when it should connect with myusername, and thirdly, script misses some error checks, because it prints that all databases were successfully backed up, when in reality nothing was backed up at all.

Also looking in script looks like it should use everything properly as provided in pg_backup.config, but it does not..

Comment: what happens if you manually run pg_backup -c [path to pg_backup.config]

Comment: When I run: `bash pg_backup.sh -c pg_backup.config`, I get these errors:
`pg_backup.sh: line 26: cd: pg_backup.sh: Not a directory
pg_backup.sh: line 27: /pg_backup.config: No such file or directory
Making backup directory in /home/mysuername/openerp/7.0/backup2013-04-24/`

when i run command as you told (`pg_backup.config -c ~/openerp/backup_script/pg_backup.config`), I just get this error:
`-bash: pg_backup.config: command not found`

Comment: pg_backup.sh -c ~/openerp/backup_script/pg_backup.config

Comment: get the same error. Both pg_backup.sh and pg_backup.config are in same directory, so it should be `bash pg_backup.sh -c pg_backup.config`, but its the same.

Comment: try getting to a shell prompt and running pg_backup.sh -c pg_backup.config without rather than bash pg_backup.sh -c pg_backup.config

Comment: what do you mean by shell prompt? I'm always on shell prompt.